# kivy library is installed but once I write a script in VS code an ImportError occurs

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

when I try to reinstall kivy here's what happens:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJb9x.png)
when I write a simple script such as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD5FQ.png)
using kivy the following error occurs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFUR4.png)

I tried to reinstall kivy and follow the specific guide on their website, but the same error happens again. then I tried to google the "error message" but noone happens to have the same problem.

I also tried to create the python file in the directory "kevy deps build" , and no good result. in addition to that I tried to run the python script from the cmd in the mentioned directory.

at last I tried to reinstall kivy using the VS terminal but there was no use.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post the code and the full error message as plain text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: For one thing, the import should be `from kivy.uix.label import Label`, not `from kivy.uix import Label`.